# HTML syntax highlighting on JavaScript questions

Tags: bug, syntax-highlighting

It's common for questions tagged [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) to have answers containing HTML code snippets, but it seems like they often aren't being highlighted properly.

For example, in [Restart animation in CSS3: any better way than removing the element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6268508/restart-animation-in-css3-any-better-way-than-removing-the-element#6303311), the first tag is consistently highlighted wrong:
[image: screenshot of highlighted code]
It's trying to highlight it as JavaScript, then switching to XML highlighting after a few lines:
[image: screenshot of html inspector]

I assume it detects the language based on the question's tags, so perhaps HTML should be prioritized on questions tagged [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript), [css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css), etc. (and vice versa)?

Comment: Unfortunately when there are tags with different default highlighting the system lets highlight.js choose. There's nothing to stop it from choosing _any_ supported language (not just the ones associated with the question tags). For example [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6458172/15497888) also on a question tagged [html] [javascript] is syntax highlighted with lang-typescript and lang-ruby. There's a feature request on MSE [Stop guessing/auto-detecting a language when you KNOW it will be incorrect](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/355852/1099857)

Comment: From the [canonical here on MSO](/a/274372/15497888): "If two or more tags on the question have different syntax highlighting languages defined, it uses a default list and lets highlight.js infer what's the best language to use."

Comment: The only way to fix this is to edit any post that doesn't have correct code highlight so that it uses code fences with a language specified, like I just did for most of the answers there. (Given the state of the suggested edit queue, I don't think I would recommend making edits that only do that if you have <2k rep.) Note: For HTML with embedded CSS and JS, the best bet is still to hint HTML.